# Symbolic machine learning with OpenStreetMap data

Tags: openstreetmap, geotag, machine-learning

I want to apply symbolic machine learning (e.g. case-based reasoning, inductive logic programming) to OSM data. In detail, I want to use OSM Map Features to predict characteristics of residential buildings.

Does anyone know algorithms, applications or related work to that problem?

Comment: Can you name us an example of a residential building characteristic that could be predicted out of OSM data? I have trouble understanding your question and I guess I won't be the only one.

Comment: e.g. single-family home or multi-apartment home, or if the building is next to the city centre or in the country

Comment: But that's nothing which has to be "predicted". This kind of information is already available within OSM, at least partly.

Comment: Yes, some of these information are present in OSM, but the density of information is low. I'm searching for a method to combine OSM data with other data sources to retrieve information about private houses - symbolic machine learning could be a solution for that.

Comment: Please switch to the OSM Forum/mailinglists as your question is pretty broad. Please see [Wiki Research](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Research) for papers and projects related to OSM